# Highcharts y-axis plotlines label hides the tooltip

Tags: highcharts

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4R5HH/209/ - this is just for testing.

I have a target label on y-axis which hides the series tooltip when hover over them.

any solution to this.

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Dummy Data by Region'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia']
        },
        yAxis: {
            plotLines:[{
                value:75,
                color: '#ff0000',
                width:2,
                zIndex:4,
                label:{text:'goal'},
                dashStyle: 'line',
                label: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    text: '<div class="targetLabel"><span>Target</span><br/><span style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px;">' + '75' + '</span></div>',
                    align: 'center',
                    rotation: 0
                },
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 50]
        },
                {
            name: 'Goal',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            data: [450]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Hi, can you please mention what is the question? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean that tooltip is "below", blue Target circle?

Comment: Tooltip is hidden behind the Target label. So how can the tooltip be displayed above the Target label.

Comment: You need to disable tooltip, and create new one as html div. Because you have two types of elements (html and SVG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from the Highcharts forum. 
So adding the link for reference - http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/highcharts-y-axis-plotlines-label-hides-the-tooltip-t31539/

Comment: You have to post the answer here, not just a link.

Comment: Its a jsFiddle so better to have it as a link.